# Maven issues in Eclipse when trying to use Selenium 3.4

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, nullpointerexception

I am trying to move a Java project from Selenium 2.53 to 3.4. I am using Eclipse Mars under Windows 7. Eactly the same problem happens in a fresh installation of Eclipse Neon.

I have changed the Maven dependency to selenium-java 3.4 and got NullPointerException when trying to run the project in Eclipse. After a Maven build of pom.xml, the resulting jar runs fine.

I thought the project might have gotten corrupted, so I started a new Maven project, hoping to move the code into it eventually. After creating a simple Maven project I added selenium-java 3.4 as a dependency - and immediately got an error during the project build in Eclipse. The details say, again, NullPointerException. Then I installed Neon,created a new project again, added selenium-java 3.4 as a dependency and got the same issue.

Unfortunately I have no way of knowing on what line the NPE happens. When trying to save pom.xml, I get a windows saying:

'Building workspace' has encountered a problem. Errors occurred during the build.

When I click Details I see:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'service.apm.ui_auto.dataentry'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

When I look into Errors, all I see is "Project configuration is not up to date with pom.xml. Select Maven -> Update project from the project context menu or use Quick fix". When I do that, I just get another window with "'Updating Maven Project' has encountered a problem". And the Details button shows a message about the NPE again.

After a lot of "trying stuff" I have stumbled upon an apparent solution. 
I rename `C:\Users\myuser\.m2` and then the new project starts working just fine - it builds, runs, Maven Update project works... until I try to build the old project. As soon as I try to build the old project or update it (right click old project > Maven > Update project), the Null Pointer Exception returns, and then it affects the new project too.

Moreover, even if I do not touch the old project, the NPE eventually returns, apparently during downloading sources and javadoc. While I will try disabling downloading sources and javadoc, this does not look like a complete solution.

Comment: NPE on what line? Please show the code if not we're just guessing.

Comment: Did you try: right click on project -> maven -> update maven project -> mark force update to last... -> update. After that: right click on project -> run -> run maven clean and then do it again to run maven install.

Comment: I have now tried right click on project -> maven -> update project. The closest one to mark was "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases". I marked that, started the update, and got the NPE again. Maven clean and Maven install are successful but change nothing at all.

Comment: Also run the maven clean and maven install again. If still get problem, you can try by using maven command line at folder of pom.xml: `mvn install`

Comment: The command was successful but nothing has changed in Eclipse.

Comment: If the command line build successful then update maven project again to take affect to eclipse project. The problem must be solved

Comment: I have updated the project and got the NPE again. It happens in the update itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143548/discussion-between-tuyen-nguyen-and-mikhail-ramendik).

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, running Eclipse Mars 4.5.2. I can get any version below 3.4.0 to run, including (currently) 3.31, but that 3.4 is a no-go...

Comment: The sort-of-solution I eventually found was installing Neon, deleting .m2, starting a completely new project from scratch, and adding the Selenium dependency. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of "trying stuff" I have finally stumbled upon an apparent solution. It was not great, but I am placing it here for the benefit of others who get the issue.

I have:

- Installed Eclipse Neon in a separate directory and with a separate workspace
- deleted C:\Users\myuser\.m2
- created a new project from scratch, and did NOT import the old projects into the new Neon

Now things seem to work fine, though at one point, the NPE returned - I think updating the indexes corrupted the repository again. I deleted .m2 and the NPE went away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a maven build issue with current version of selenium jars 3.4.0, so what worked for me was adding dependency for a lower version of selenium, in this case, version 3.3.1. Once added and saved, no error was seen and the project was successfully built.